# Unable to connect to MongoDB: Failed to connect to: 333.33.333.333:27017: Connection refused

Tags: php, mongodb

Hello am trying to connect mongodb on live server using codeigniter an getting following error .

Unable to connect to MongoDB: Failed to connect to: Connection refused

Everything working fine on my local machine.

here is my connection setting in mongo_db.php file in config folder

```
$config['mongo_db']['default']['no_auth'] = FALSE;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['hostname'] = '333.33.333.333';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['port'] = '27017';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['username'] = 'abcd';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['password'] = 'abcdef';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['database'] = 'db_seeker';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['return_as'] = 'array';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['write_concerns'] = (int)1;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['journal'] = TRUE;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['read_preference'] = NULL;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['read_preference_tags'] = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

333.33.333.333 is not a valid ip, so I doubt your server is binded to that ip

Comment: No its just for example  my ip is different

Comment: can you ping the remote server ?
can you telnet the remote server on the 27017 port ?
can you connect on mongodb with the command line client ?